# Get all categories by store with SOAP Magento

Tags: php, magento, soap

I can see in Magento docs that categories.tree can be called with an optional store view parameter, but I can't make it work.

I am doing the following:

```
$store = 'gl'; // This is my store view code
return self::$client->call( self::$session, 'catalog_category.tree' , $store );
```

But I get a SOAP error. How showld I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$client->call(self::$session, 'catalog_category.tree' , null, $store );
```

You are not passing the second parameter, that ([as per documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalog/catalogCategory/catalog_category.tree.html)) corresponds to the parentId, and I think that you want to ignore it.

The equivalent call for the SOAPv2 API would be:

```
$client->catalogCategoryTree(self::$session, null, $store);
```